# Query using Mysql Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `T` and `T1` 
T

```
 id   p   o 
 1    47  1
 2    47  2
 3    47  25
```

T1

```
id   p    
 1    47  
 2    48  
 3    49
```

I am looking to find a way to get T as the following table

```
     id   p   o 
     1    47  1
     2    47  2
     3    47  0
```

If `T.p in (select T1.p from T1)` and the value of the field `o` is the max then update `o`
into `0`.
I try the following query but it didn't work

```
Update T
SET T.o=0
WHERE T.P IN (select T1.p from T INNER join select T.p from T ON T.p=T1.p)
AND T.o In (select Max(T.o) from T)
```

For more details [Sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed2a9a/3)

Many thanks in advance .

Comment: does this update query work on your 'real' database?  It won't work on the sqlfiddle page, since you can't update those tables, only SELECT statements are allowed.

Comment: @BWS you can run update,delete on the left side.

Comment: Well, there ya go ... I learned something new today!  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71c21/1)

```
Update T
SET T.o=0
WHERE T.P IN (select T1.p from t1 ) 
AND t.o IN (SELECT * FROM(SELECT MAX(t.o) FROM t)x)
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
UPDATE T
SET T.o=0
WHERE T.p in (select T1.p from T1) 
AND T.o In (select Max(T.o) from T)
```

Comment: IN mysql,you can`t specify directly in the FROM clause the table you update.